Application of the mean value theorem on twice differentiable functions
$f:\mathbb{R} \to [0,\infty)$ is a twice differentiable function such that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$ and $f(x)+1=\dfrac{1}{f''(x)}$ for every $x \in [0,1]$. Show that $f(1)<\frac{3}{2}$ in this case.
In order to solve this question, I used the mean value theorem for $f'$ and $f''$ and obtained some results using equality, but this did not lead me to the desired proof. Like
$f''(0)=1 , f''(1)=\dfrac{1}{1+f(1)}$ , $f'(x_1)=\dfrac{f(1)-f(0)}{1-0}=f(1) \ \exists x_1 \in [0,1] $ and $f''(x_2)=\dfrac{f'(x_1)-f'(0)}{x_1-0}=\dfrac{f(1)}{x_1} \ \exists x_1 \in [0,x_1]$

Are you looking exclusively for a proof using MVT or just for a proof in general?

I am looking for a general proof

You are right I changed it sorry

It should be $f(1)<3/2$.
Notice that, as $f$ is non-negative and differentiable and $f''(x)=\dfrac{1}{f(x)+1}$, $f$ is infinitely differentiable. By Taylor's Theorem, we may write $$f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+\dfrac{f''(0)}{2}x^2+\dfrac{f'''(\xi_x)}{6}x^3$$ for some $\xi_x\in (0,x)$.
In particular, for $x=1$, using that $f(0)=0, f'(0)=1$ and $f''(0)=\dfrac{1}{f(0)+1}=1$, we get $$f(1)=0+1\cdot 1+\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot 1^2+\dfrac{f'''(\xi)}{6}=\dfrac{3}{2}+\dfrac{f'''(\xi)}{6}$$
for some $\xi\in (0,1)$. It suffices to show that $f'''(x)<0$ for all $x\in (0,1)$, or, equivalently, that $f''$ is strictly decreasing on $(0,1)$.
But $f''(x)=\dfrac{1}{f(x)+1}$, so proving that $f$ is strictly increasing is enough.
But, as $f$ is non-negative, $f''(x)\geq 0$ and thus $f'$ increases. Given that $f'(0)=1$ we have $f'(x)>1>0$ on $(0,1)$. This means that $f$ increases and by the logic above $f'''(\xi)<0$, which proves that $f(1)<3/2$.
